# What are the formulas used in SAGA Ordinary Kriging?

Tags: interpolation, saga, kriging, model, formula

can some one name the formulas avaible in the Ordinary Kriging Modul of SAGA:

[image]

What ist the exponential, spherical, Gaussian-Model, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear Regression:

- `a + b * x`
- `a + b * x + c * x^2`
- `a + b * x + c * x^2 + d * x^3`
- `a + b * x + c * x^2 + d * x^3 + e * x^4`

Logarithmic Model:

- `a + b * ln(x)`

Power Model:

- `a + b * x^c`

Gaussian Model:

- `a + b * (1 – exp(-(x /b)^2))`

Spherical Model:

- `a + b * ifelse(x > c, 1, 1.5 * x / c - 0.5 * x^3 / c^3)`

I don't know  `a + b * sqrt(x)`.